# Mixing xpath and simple expression in Camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I am just wondering if it is possible to mix XPath expression with a Camel `simple` expression.

The case:

In my `configure()` method of my route I have the code:

```
    Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("sys1", "urn:com:example:namespace:system/1");

    directFrom("from")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
        .to("{{request.endpoint}}")
        .choice()
            .when(header(STATUS_CODE).isEqualTo(200))
                .choice()
                    .when(xpath("count(//sys1:UsageType[@code='0003'])>0").namespaces(ns))
                        .setHeader(STATUS_CODE,constant(404))
                        .setHeader(STATUS_MESSAGE,simple("Not found"))
                        .setBody(constant("Not found"))
                        .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("xslt:xslt/response.xsl?transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl")
                        .endChoice()
                .end()
                .endChoice()
        .end();
```

I want the value in the XPath expression to be configurable: is it possible to have something like this in the xpath expression:

```
.when(xpath("count(//sys1:UsageType[@code='${properties:filter.value}'])>0").namespaces(ns)))
```

I use the same syntax as a `simple` expression.

The only way I found is to inject (with blueprint) the whole XPath (or just the value) in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html):

```
// Following properties are given:
// foo=Camel
// bar=Kong
from("direct:in").choice()
    // $type is a variable for the header with key type
    // here we use the properties function to lookup foo from the properties files
    // which at runtime will be evaluted to 'Camel'
    .when().xpath("$type = function:properties(&#39;foo&#39;)")
        .to("mock:camel")
    // here we use the simple language to evaluate the expression
    // which at runtime will be evaluated to 'Donkey Kong'
    .when().xpath("//name = function:simple('Donkey ${properties:bar}')")
        .to("mock:donkey")
    .otherwise()
        .to("mock:other")
    .end();
```

Thus, something like that should work:

```
.when(xpath("count(//sys1:UsageType[@code=function:simple('${properties:filter.value}')])>0").namespaces(ns))
```

Comment: I tried this `.when(xpath("count(//sys1:UsageType[@code=function:simple('${properties:filter.value}'])>0").namespaces(ns))` but it does not look to work. Notice I made a mistake in the when() clause: it should be closed with only 2 parenthesis, not three.

Comment: Finally i succeed to make it work. I had different problem (properly loading properties inside junit test) and a missing closing parenthesis in your code (I edited your post)